# Java can't stop a boolean function from playing on every repeat of the program

Tags: java

Everything works as it should apart from when I press 3 for "no feedback given" it still gives the feedback "Unlucky, try again!". Is there a way around this so that when I press 3 to not have feedback, it doesn't have that extra bit of code popping in?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class GameVer2 {
public static void main(String []args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);    



        String inputName;
        System.out.print("Enter your name here...");
        inputName = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Hi "+ inputName + ", Welcome! ");



        int tries = 0;
        int count = 0;
        boolean responses = true;
        boolean reboot = true;
        while(reboot){


           do{

                            Random randomNumberChooser = new Random();

                            int ranNum1;
                            ranNum1 = randomNumberChooser.nextInt(11)+2;
                            int ranNum2;
                            ranNum2 = randomNumberChooser.nextInt(11)+2;
                            int SysAns = (ranNum1 * ranNum2);

                    if(tries == 0){
                             int inputResponses;
                             System.out.println("Would you like feedback on your answers? Press 1 for yes and 3 for no.");
                             inputResponses = userInput.nextInt();
                        if(inputResponses == 1){
                            responses = true;
                            System.out.println("You will receive feedback on your answers.");
                        }
                        if(inputResponses == 3){
                            System.out.println("No feedback will be given.");
                            responses = false;
                        }
                    }

                            String question;
                            System.out.println("How much is " + ranNum1 +" x " + ranNum2 + "?");
                            tries = tries + 1;
                            int num = userInput.nextInt();

                    if(num == SysAns){
                        System.out.println("Correct!");
                        count = count + 1;

                            System.out.println("Excellent form on that one!");
                            responses = true;
                        }

                    if(num != SysAns){
                        System.out.println("Incorrect! The correct answer was: " + SysAns);

                            System.out.println("Unlucky, try again!");
                            responses = true;


                        }


                }while(tries <10 );

                if(tries == 10){
                    int userAnswer;
                    System.out.println("Your score: " + count);  

                        if(count == 0){
                            System.out.println(inputName + ", you gave no correct answers - see me!");
                        }
                        if(count > 0 && count <5){
                            System.out.println(inputName + ", you only gave " + count + " correct answers, please revise your times tables!");
                        }
                        if(count >4 && count <9){
                            System.out.println(inputName + ", you gave " + count + " correct answers - good!");
                        }
                        if(count == 9){
                            System.out.println (inputName + ", you gave 9 correct answers - very good!");
                        }
                        if(count == 10){
                            System.out.println ("Excellent, you gave 10 correct answers! - Well Done " + inputName + "!");
                        }
                    System.out.print(inputName + ", would you like to keep playing? Press 1 to play on, or 3 to quit. ");
                    userAnswer = userInput.nextInt();

                    if(userAnswer == 1 ){
                        reboot = true;
                         tries = 0;
                         count = 0;

                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.print("Thank you for playing our game!");
                        reboot = false;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Use an if statement? (Is this a trick question?)

Comment: New to this, I thought I had used one on this line: if(inputResponses == 3){
                            System.out.println("No feedback will be given.");
                            responses = false;
                        }

Comment: Some weird behavior results sometimes when using scanner.hasNextInt() (Not 100% positive, but I think it doesn't pick up the new line when you enter your int). Honestly, I would read the input as a string using: Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());    Try this and it should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an if statement.  Nest the two response if statements in one testing whether to give responses:

```
if(responses)
{
    if(num==sysAns){...}
    if(num!=sysAns){...}
}
```

Comment: why don't use `if {num == sysAns} else {}`? it's much clearer and will avoid another comparison on dumb compilers

Answer (score 0):

replace code of if block

```
 if (inputResponses == 3) {
                        System.out.println("No feedback will be given.");
                        responses = false;
                    }
```

with

```
 if (inputResponses == 3) {
                        System.out.println("No feedback will be given.");
                        responses = false;
                        reboot = false;
                        break;
                    }
```